# Tools for Cordova CTP3 Unknown encoding MDAVSCLI

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I'm writing a new Cordova hybrid app using Visual Studio Community 2013. After creating my first `blankCordovaApp`, I am get the error when I try to run it (after clicking on the running-`F5` icon).

```
Error   1   Unknown encoding
  C:\Users\Name\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\MDAVSCLI
  1     1   BlankCordovaApp1
```

Here is the full console output

```
------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
Build started 4/25/2015 8:52:16 PM.
CompileTypeScript:
  Skipping target "CompileTypeScript" because all output files are up-to
  -date with respect to the input files.
TrackJsChanges:
  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\file.js;scripts\file.js.map
InstallMDATargets: 
  C:\Users\kamdjou\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\Blank CordovaApp
  call "C:\Program
  Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat  
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm. 
------ Ensuringcorrect global installation of package from source package directory:
  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\54A1XF3K.KIB\packages\vs-mda 
BuildMDA: 
  C:\Users\kamdjou\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\Blank CordovaApp
  "C:\Users\kamdjou\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli.cmd"
    build --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName BlankCordovaApp1
    --npmInstallDir C:\Users\kamdjou\AppData\Roaming\npm --language en-US --buildTarget AndroidEmulator  

buffer.js:440 
    throw new Error('Unknown encoding'); 
          ^ MDAVSCLI : error :
Unknown encoding 
  at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:440:13) 
  at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:236:33) 
  at new BuildSettings (C:\Users\kamdjou\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\BuildSettings.js:64:41) 
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kamdjou\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\app.js:35:16) 
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10) 
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
  at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10) 
  at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9) 

Build FAILED. 

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.52
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I formatted the build log output, which makes it easier to see where the encoding problem arises. I also added a few corrections on your English, which is quite good on the whole. Cheers!

Comment: Have you considered moving to CTP3.1 from CT3.0 (your title implies you are still using the older CTP3)?  I have not seen this specific issue before but there were numerous bug fixes made in the recently released CTP3.1 which might address this issue.  Or you could upgrade to VS 2015 RC which was also just released.